# Is it possible that the energy of the energy eigenstates $|LSJM_J\rangle$ depend on $M_L$ and/or $M_S$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, symmetry, atomic-physics

If a many-electron Hamiltonian $H$ commutes with ${\vec L}^2, {\vec S}^2, {\vec J}^2$, and $J_z$ but not $L_z$ and $S_z$, the energy eigenstates are designated by $|LSJM_J\rangle$.  Since there is no external field (no breakdown of rotational symmetry) that distinguishes different values of $M_J$, the energy cannot depend on $M_J$ and therefore, such a state, for a given value of $J$ will have a $(2J+1)$-fold degeneracy.

It is clear that the energy eigenstates $|LSJM_J\rangle$ are not labeled by $M_L, M_S$ because $H$ does not commute with $L_z, S_z$. But is there any chance that the energy depends on $M_L$ and/or $M_S$? Does the absence of an external field (rotational symmetry) also exclude the possibility of energy depending on $M_L$ and/or $M_S$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$M_L$ and $M_S$ are actually still good quantum numbers for stretched states even for non-zero external fields.

You have already established that the energy does not depend on $M_J$. The number of states is "conserved" as you break symmetries. Each state in the broken-LS coupling régime is "adiabatically" connected to the zero-field LS coupling régime. Meaning you can connect an $|M_L, M_S\rangle$ state at $|\mathbf{B}|\neq 0$ to an $|M_J\rangle$ state as $|\mathbf{B}|\rightarrow 0$. 
 So why would the energy depend on $M_S$ or $M_L$, if it does not depend on $M_J$?

Physically, in order for the energy to depend on the quantum number $M_L$ or $M_S$, you need an interaction that couples to the orbital ($L$) or spin ($S$) angular momentum of the electron(s) respectively. This could, for instance, be an electric field (Stark effect) or a magnetic field (Zeeman effect).  
 So if you have no external field of any kind, and therefore no interaction that would *change* the energy of the electron(s), why would there be such a dependence in the energy?

From the "symmetry" perspective, notice that it is slightly less trivial that simple rotational symmetry. 
 An external electric field along $z$ breaks rotational symmetry, but the Stark effect causes the energy splitting to go as $|m_J|$. To break the symmetry between $\pm m_J$, you need to also break time-reversal symmetry. With, for instance, an external magnetic field: the Zeeman effect, in fact, results in the energy splitting to go as $\propto m_J$.